# Which of these rings are isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Which of these rings are isomorphic:
1) $ \Bbb Z [ X] / (X^2+2X) $
2) $ \Bbb Z [ X] / (X^2 -2) $
3) $ \Bbb Z [ X] / (X^2+4X + 2) $
4) $ \Bbb Z [ X] / (X^2) $
5) $R= \{ (a,b) \in \Bbb Z ^2 \mid a \equiv b \pmod 2 \} $

All I can do for now is to say, is that I think  :
$ \Bbb Z [ X] / (X^2 -2) \cong  \Bbb Z [ \sqrt2] $.
Why? If we define  $ f: \Bbb Z [ X] \rightarrow \Bbb C $, $ f(X)= \sqrt2, f(p)=p, p \in \Bbb Z$
then it is obviously a homomorphism, and it's kernel is $(X^2-2)$, so by the First Isomorphism Theorem we got what we wanted.

Unfortunately, I am unable to find the solutions of other ones.
I have only checked, that
$ \Bbb Z [ X] / (X^2+4X + 2) \cong  \Bbb Z [ X] / ((X-2-\sqrt3)(X-2+\sqrt3)) $

And, probably none of those are isomorphic to $ \Bbb Z  \times \Bbb Z $, because the ideals are not comaximal.

I would very appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) $ \Bbb Z [ X] / (X^2+2X) $ has no non-trivial nilpotents, but it's not an integral domain.
2) $ \Bbb Z [ X] / (X^2 -2) $ is an integral domain since $X^2-2$ is irreducible.
3) $ \Bbb Z [ X] / (X^2+4X + 2) $ is an integral domain since $X^2+4X+2$ is irreducible.
4) $ \Bbb Z [ X] / (X^2) $ has non-trivial nilpotents.
5) $R= \{ (a,b) \in \Bbb Z ^2 \mid a\equiv b \bmod 2 \} $ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z[X]/(X^2-2X)$.

The only remaining possibilities are 2) with 3), and 1) with 5), and these are isomorphic via $X\to X+2$.

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas:

For (1),for example, define

$$\phi:\Bbb Z[x]\to\Bbb Z[x]/\langle x\rangle\times\Bbb Z[x]/\langle x+2\rangle\;,\;\;\phi(f(x)):=(f(0)\,,\,\,f(-2))$$

Now, each factor above is an integral domain (why?). Try to complete the idea.

Something similar can be done with (4). In (2)-(3) both ideals dividing are prime. What you write in your last line of calculations cannot be right since you're trying to form a quotient ring of $\;\Bbb Z[x]\;$ dividing by and ideal generated by elements **not** in $\;\Bbb Z[x]\;$ .

Comment: I agree with the second part, that you wrote.

Hmm you want to say that $ \Bbb Z [ X] / (X^2+2X)$ is isomorphic with $  \Bbb Z [ X] / (X) \times  \Bbb Z [ X] / (X+2) $? I dont think it's possible because $(X)$ and $(X+2)$ are not comaximal in $ \Bbb Z[X]$. 

Maybe you wanted me to think about something else - but unfortunately I don't know what else can I do in this situation